# I am sending some variables from a select to another Landing Page but the variables do not carry the value I select in the select

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, developer

I am sending some variables from a select to another Landing Page but the variables do not carry the value I select in the select.

````
%%[
SET @SubmitPage = "https://url"
]%%

                 
       
                <div class="row">
                 <form action="%%=v(@SubmitPage)=%%" method="get">
                  
                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
                          <div class="card border-left-info shadow h-100" style="background:#04BF33 !important; color: #FFFFFF !important;">
                            <div class="card-body"> 
                            <label for="ofertas">Seleccione Cupon a Asignar:</label>
                            <select class="ofertas" id="ofertas" name="ofertas">
  
 %%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @i


set @TIPO__CUP = "Brick"
set @rows = LookupRows("Cupones","TIPO__CUP", @TIPO__CUP)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)



if @rowCount > 0 then

  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @rank
    set @row = row(@rows, @i)
    set @NRO_CUPON_CUP = field(@row,"NRO_CUPON_CUP")
    set @DESCRIPCION_CUP = field(@row,"DESCRIPCION_CUP")
    set @FECHA_INICIO_CUP = field(@row,"FECHA_INICIO_CUP")
    set @FECHA_FIN_CUP = field(@row,"FECHA_FIN_CUP")
  
]%%
<option value="%%[OUTPUTLINE(@NRO_CUPON_CUP)]%%"> %%[OUTPUTLINE(CONCAT(@NRO_CUPON_CUP))]%% </option>
     
%%[next @i ]%%
  
  
%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
     
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  
             
                   
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
                    <div class="card border-left-info shadow h-100" style="background:#04BF33 !important; color: #FFFFFF !important;">
                        <div class="card-body"> 
                            <label for="segmentos">Seleccione un Segmento: </label>
                            <select class="segmentos" id="segmentos" name="segmentos">
                              
%%[

var @rr, @CategoryID, @Name, @CustomerKey

set @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "DataExtension")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "CategoryID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "Name")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "CustomerKey")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "CreatedDate")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "Description")




set @sfp = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "Property", "CategoryID")
SetObjectProperty(@sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@sfp, "Value", "13444")

SetObjectProperty(@rr,"Filter", @sfp)


set @rows = InvokeRetrieve(@rr, @rrStatus, @rrRequestID)


for @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) do

  set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
    set @CategoryID = Field(@row, "CategoryID")
  set @Name = Field(@row,"Name")
  set @CustomerKey = Field(@row, "CustomerKey")
  set @CreatedDate = Field(@row, "CreatedDate")
  set @Description = Field(@row, "Description")
  
]%%
<option value="%%[OUTPUTLINE(@Name)]%%"> %%[OUTPUTLINE(CONCAT(@Name))]%% </option>


%%[next @i]%%  
                          </select>
                          
                         <p style="text-align:center"><input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Guardar cambios" style="margin-top: 2%"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>     
 </div>
          ``` 
the following is the evidence of what sends the variables in the url:

ofertas=%0D%0A&segmentos=%0D%0A
````

Comment: Does it output the `<option>` correctly?

Comment: Also, I’d try changing `method="get"` to `method="post"` to see if that helps

Comment: yes, the Option is shown correctly, the method="get" I use it to see what the variables carry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > You cann use [OutputLine](https://ampscript.guide/outputline/) only as a nested function.

your current code is displaying the value as you are using, `Concat`

```ampscript
%%[OUTPUTLINE(CONCAT(@NRO_CUPON_CUP))]%%
```

But while assigning value in Option tag, you are missing the `Concat`

```ampscript
<option value="%%[OUTPUTLINE(@NRO_CUPON_CUP)]%%">
```

Similarly for other Select tag.

> > Also `OutputLine` function inserts a line feed character after the result!
> > This would lead to a look something as below!
> > [image]

Hence please use `Output` instead of `OutputLine`

---

---

just use as below in both <option>' tags.

```ampscript
<option value="%%[Output(Concat(@NRO_CUPON_CUP))]%%"> %%[Output(Concat(@NRO_CUPON_CUP))]%% </option>
```

Comment: @CV de Vishal Kumar I was just that thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome @JeferssonGomez

Comment: Why not just use `%%=v()=%%`? That seems the path of least resistance as its inline and not in a block